# How to update array list with objects created in another fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have two fragments A and B. In fragment A I have a recyclerview created from an arraylist of objects ( ex: person object with fields age height name weight) at the bottom of fragment A I have put a button to add new person. This button opens another fragment in which I can fill the name age weight ... of the person. When I am done filling I want the person item to appear at the end of the list. whenever I press add I want the list items to increase. Images of how layout looks like [Fragment B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlwse.jpg) [Fragment A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bef0s.jpg).

I have created person class parcelable.
To pass an object from Fragment B to Fragment A. I have used bundle.
I read the object and add it to ArrayList in method onviewcreated of Fragment A.
However, The object item is not added to the list rather than replaced. I think when I get to fragment A the whole array list is created again and not saved. I am not sure how to solve the problem. I am new to android. I have put the code below:

```
//subject class
    public class subjects implements Parcelable{
    private String name;

    private int age;
    private int weight;
    private int height;

    public subjects(@NonNull final String Name, int Age, int Weight, int Height) {

       this.name=Name;
       this.age=Age;
       this.weight=Weight;
       this.height=Height;
    }

    protected subjects(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readString();
        age = in.readInt();
        weight = in.readInt();
        height = in.readInt();
    }

    public static final Creator<subjects> CREATOR = new Creator<subjects>() {
        @Override
        public subjects createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new subjects(in);
        }

        @Override
        public subjects[] newArray(int size) {
            return new subjects[size];
        }
    };

    @NonNull
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @NonNull
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    @NonNull
    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
    @NonNull
    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeInt(age);
        dest.writeInt(weight);
        dest.writeInt(height);
    }
}



//frament B

    /**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class newsubject extends Fragment {
    private Button btn_add;
    private EditText et_name,et_surname,et_age,et_height,et_weight;


    public newsubject() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View FragmentView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_newsubject, container, false);

        btn_add = (Button) FragmentView.findViewById(R.id.Add);
        et_name=(EditText) FragmentView.findViewById(R.id.subjname);
        et_age=(EditText) FragmentView.findViewById(R.id.subjage);
        et_weight=(EditText) FragmentView.findViewById(R.id.subjweight);
        et_height=(EditText) FragmentView.findViewById(R.id.subjheight);

        btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                subjects subject=new subjects(et_name.getText().toString(),Integer.parseInt(et_age.getText().toString()),Integer.parseInt(et_weight.getText().toString()),Integer.parseInt(et_height.getText().toString()));
                Registration fragment = new Registration(); //Your Fragment
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putParcelable("subj", subject);  // Key, value
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                getFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.FLfragment, fragment)
                        .commit();

            }
        });



        return FragmentView;
    }

}
```

fragment A

```
//fragment A
public class Registration extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private SubjectAdapter msubjectadapter;
    private List<subjects> subjectlist;
    private Button btn_addsubject;


    public Registration() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View FragmentView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_registeration, container, false);
        btn_addsubject= (Button) FragmentView.findViewById(R.id.addsubject);

        btn_addsubject.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                newsubject NewSubject = new newsubject();
                FragmentTransaction transaction= getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.FLfragment,NewSubject);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });

        createSubjectList();
        buildRecyclerView(FragmentView);

        msubjectadapter.SetOnClickListener(new SubjectAdapter.OnClickItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You clicked " + subjectlist.get(position).getName() + " on row number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            }

        });



        return FragmentView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            subjects s = (subjects) bundle.getParcelable("subj"); // Key
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+s.getHeight() + s.getName() + s.getAge() +s.getWeight(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            subjectlist.add(s);
            msubjectadapter.notifyItemInserted(0);

        }
    }

    public void buildRecyclerView(View FView){
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) FView.findViewById(R.id.subjects);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(FView.getContext()));
        msubjectadapter= new SubjectAdapter(subjectlist);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(msubjectadapter);
    }

    public void createSubjectList(){
        subjectlist = new ArrayList<>();
        subjectlist.add(new subjects("person1",23,52,160));
        subjectlist.add(new subjects("person2",23,80,180));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
}
'''
```

EDIT:
[I add person 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGaja.jpg) [I add person 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5YpS.png) the problem is that person 3 is deleted. The array list is recreated in Fragment A with the arraylist defined there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In your activity(activity where your fragment A and fragment B created),
Create method

```
public void loadFragmentA(YourModelClass object) {
        FragmentA fragment = new FragmentA();
        Bundle b1 = new Bundle();
        b1.putSerializable("key", object);
        

        fragment.setArguments(b1);
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Now in Fragment B, "Add" button click

```
((YOUR_ACTIVITY_WHERE_FRAGMENT_CREATED_AND_ABOVE_METHOD_ADDED) getActivity()).loadFragmentA(YourModelClass_OBJECT_IN_WHICH_NEW_DATA_ADDED);
```

And implement your model class as "Serializable",
When you get in Fragment A get like

```
YourModelClass object = (YourModelClass)getArguments().getSerializable("key");
```

Hope this work, let me know if not work.

Comment: I dont create Fragment B in The activity. I create Fragment B in Fragment A. I am not sure it is the right way. I do that because the only way to open Fragment B is from Fragment A by pressing the ADD button. Check  btn_addsubject click listener. Also, I create the object in fragment B so I need to get it back to Fragment A and add it to the list. However the problem is that the array list is not getting updated.

Comment: you have "FrameLayout" in your xml class of activity? and in that you are adding fragment right?

Comment: "R.id.FLfragment" this  "FLfragment" is in your activity right?

Comment: yea, so in your activity your adding your atleast on fragment in  "R.id.FLfragment" right?

Comment: The Problem: when I get back to Fragment A. I think the function onCreateView is run again so ( list = new arraylist .. is executed again) ..so list.add(object) is added to the arraylist which is emptied due to the onCreateView. The new object added is not saved in fragment A. If I leave Fragment A and then come back I will not find this added subject. I think this is my problem... I think I passing of object part from Fragment B to Fragment A is working fine. Is it clear :/? Thank you very much

Comment: yes, so what you need to do is, when you add new person in Fragment B, you have to pass new person data in arguments. If possible create chat so i can explain better

Comment: I dont have create chat privilege. Is there any other way?

Comment: `Registration fragment = new Registration(); //Fragment A
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putParcelable("subj", subject);  // Key, value
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                getFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.FLfragment, fragment)
                        .commit();` I used this to pass new person to Fragment A. Is this similar to what you were suggesting. this is found in btn_add click listener in Fragment B

Comment: yes, try bundle.putserializable("subj", subject);  // Key, value

Comment: I tried it. I already had it in the code. I have put images to further explain. I am really sorry for this. Thank you ! @pratik vekariya

Comment: as per you have added image, at bottom there is edittext and "add" button, so tell me if i am wrong or write, 

basically as per my thinking you want to add your edittext value on "Add" click in above list(recycler view) 

is this right?

Comment: There are two add buttons. Add button in fragment A gets you to Fragment B. The Add button in Fragment B creats a new person object from the information given in the edit texts then gets you back to Fragment A. The edit text in Fragment A has no role in anything. I am sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Use the interface approach in this case :

```
  interface UpdateList{
       void updateList(YourClass obj);
  }

 class FragmentA extends Fragment implements UpdateList{
      ..Methods..

      public void updateList(YourClass obj){
           list.add(obj);
           adapter.notifydatasetchanged();
      } 
 }

class FragmentB extends Fragment{
     ..Methods..

     public void onAdd(){
         UpdateList fragment = (UpdateList) getParentFragment();
         fragment.updateList(your_object_with_data);
         //close this fragment
     }
}
```